# Understanding QuickSort Syntax

Tags: java, syntax, quicksort, bounding

I'm confused by this syntax because at first it appears as though the function should return `<E>` but then I see `void`.  What is the purpose of the `<E>` prior to the `void`?

Also, I'm familiar with bounding and generics, but I've never actually seen something bounded this way.  What does this syntax mean `Comparator<? super E>`?

Here is a sample function:

```
private <E> void sort(E[] array, Comparator<? super E>  cmp) {
   qsort(array, 0, array.length - 1, cmp);
}
```

Comment: "What is the purpose of the `<E>` prior to the void?" It shows it's a generic method. "What does this syntax mean `Comparator<? super E>`?" See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, Jon.  Is that syntax optional?

Comment: @inquisitor: Not when you're declaring a generic method, no.

Comment: @inquisitor when you're wondering about some feature of Java, like generics, just google for "Java <feature> tutorial" (so in this case "Java generics tutorial"), and the first result is usually the right one. Java tutorials contain detailed explanations, full of examples.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for that.  I wasn't sure initially how to google for the answer mainly because it was sytnax related.  But you're right, will do so in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `<E>` is not a type - it is a type constraint.

Bear in mind that Java implements generics via type erasure - this means that the runtime type signature of this method is

```
private void sort(Object[] array, Comparator cmp)
```

(by removing everything in between the `<>`s) so your method has return type `void`.

What `<E>` does is to say that the types of the input array and comparator are related: the comparator needs to be able to compare 'things' of type `E`, but it actually doesn't have to only handle things of the *exact* type `E`.

This is what `<? super E>` does: for example, you could have a `Comparator<CharSequence>`, and then use that to sort `String[]`, since `String` is a subclass of `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 3):

> at first it appears as though the function should return `<E>` but then I see `void`

The `<E>` part there is a syntax for supplying generic methods their type argument. The actual return type is `void`.

> What does this syntax mean `Comparator<? super E>`

This means that the comparator may be for `E` or for any of its superclasses.

Answer (score 2):

```
Comparator<? super E>
```

? is the wildcard character and the lower bound for this is E.

for example:

```
private <E> void sort(E[] array, Comparator<? super E>  cmp)
```

if you are passing

```
qsort(array, 0, array.length - 1, cmp);
```

if **array is Number[]** then lower bound of **"?"** is set to java.lang.Number ie **"?"** can be anything which is a super class of Number.